# Mongoid: embeds_one and _destroy param at embedded documents

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have such model.

```
    class Article
      include Mongoid::Document          
      embeds_many :blocks, class_name: 'Article::Block', cascade_callbacks: true
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :blocks, allow_destroy: true
      ...

      class Block   
        include Mongoid::Document
        embedded_in :article
        embeds_one :squib, class_name:'Article::Block::Squib', cascade_callbacks: true
        accepts_nested_attributes_for :squib, allow_destroy: true            
        ...

        class Squib
           include Mongoid::Document
           ...
           embedded_in :block, class_name: 'Article::Block'
        end
      end
    end
```

problem is about firing callbacks. When I pass to controller following params:

```
{"article"=>{"_id"=>"55d4c8a43a98c118b100001a", ... , "blocks_attributes"=>[{... "squib_attributes"=>{... "_destroy"=>1, "_id"=>"55d4ccb63a98c118b1000044"}, "_id"=>"55d4c8d73a98c118b100001c"}]}}
```

Embedded Article::Block::Squib doesn't destroys. There is no problem when I am using embeds_many relation. Problem only in embeds_one.

How to fix it?

Mongoid version 4.0.2

Comment: Do you have a spec/test which confirms this bug? In that case maybe you should create an issue with Mongoid.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you comment. I made simple example with tests: https://github.com/r00takaspin/mongoid-test. But I found solution at sources and added it as my own answer. Is it bug or feature? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution at mongoid sources. There is code with check for embeds_one relation:

```
    def delete?
      destroyable? && !attributes[:id].nil?
    end
```

mongoid-4.0.2/lib/mongoid/relations/builders/nested_attributes/one.rb:82

It means that embeds_one understands only **:id** doc identifier,instead of embeds_many, that allow you to pass embedded documents with **:_id** doc identifier.

Instead of:

> {"article"=>{"_id"=>"55d4c8a43a98c118b100001a", ... ,
>   "blocks_attributes"=>[{... "squib_attributes"=>{... "_destroy"=>1,
>   "**_id**"=>"55d4ccb63a98c118b1000044"},
>   "_id"=>"55d4c8d73a98c118b100001c"}]}}

you should pass

> {"article"=>{"_id"=>"55d4c8a43a98c118b100001a", ... ,
>   "blocks_attributes"=>[{... "squib_attributes"=>{... "_destroy"=>1,
>   "**id**"=>"55d4ccb63a98c118b1000044"},
>   "_id"=>"55d4c8d73a98c118b100001c"}]}}

to update_attributes method.